# Django IntegrityError at /doctor-add-notes NOT NULL constraint failed:

Tags: django

I am a newbie.
Enhancing a project For the current user, there are different members, for each member I want to add Notes with the current time & date. so I am using Django in-built user model.

for example

```
User1 
  Member1  Notes   Date & Time 
  Member2  Notes   Date & Time
  Member3  Notes   Date & Time

**User2** 
      Member1  Notes   Date & Time 
      Member2  Notes   Date & Time
      Member3  Notes   Date & Time
```

for now just trying to add user1, member1 Notes & Date  but after submitting the form getting an error. how to correct that,

```
IntegrityError at /doctor-add-notes
NOT NULL constraint failed: hospital_notes.user_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/doctor-add-notes
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: hospital_notes.user_id
Exception Location: C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 396
Python Executable:  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\user1\\PycharmProjects\\Project\\hospitalmanagement',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\PycharmProjects\\Project\\hospitalmanagement',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 31 Dec 2020 03:37:51 +0000
```

**Here is part of relevant code**

```
**Models**

class Notes(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    report = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    NoteDate = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

  **View:**

def doctor_add_notes_view(request):
    appointmentForm=forms.PatientNotesForm()
    mydict={'appointmentForm':appointmentForm,}
    print(mydict)
    if request.method=='POST':
        appointmentForm=forms.PatientNotesForm(request.POST)
        if appointmentForm.is_valid():
            appointment=appointmentForm.save(commit=False)
            appointment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('doctor_add_notes')
        else:
            return render(request, 'hospital/doctor_view_patient.html',{'alert_flag': True})
    return render(request,'hospital/doctor_add_notes.html',context=mydict)


**Forms:**

class PatientNotesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=models.Notes
        fields=['report']
 
**doctor_add_notes.html**

{% extends 'hospital/doctor_base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}

<head>
  <style media="screen">
    a:link {
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .note {
      text-align: center;
      height: 80px;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #0072ff, #8811c5);
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 80px;
    }

    .form-content {
      padding: 5%;
      border: 1px solid #ced4da;
      margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .form-control {
      border-radius: 1.5rem;
    }

    .btnSubmit {
      border: none;
      border-radius: 1.5rem;
      padding: 1%;
      width: 20%;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #0062cc;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .menu {
      top: 50px;
    }
  </style>

  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<br><br>

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="container register-form">
    <div class="form">
      <div class="note">
        <p>Patient Notes Details</p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-content">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              {% render_field appointmentForm.report class="form-control" placeholder="Description" %}
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btnSubmit">Book</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Your model `Notes` has a field called `user` which ***can't be NULL/None***. Since you have only defined `report` field in the `PatientNotesForm` form, Django is unable to determine the value of `user`

Comment: you have these options, provide the value for `user` 1. from Form itself 2. set default value in the model 3. set user field as nullable 4. set logged-in user as `user`

Comment: thanks do you mean add mode like this                                                                                    class PatientNotesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['report','NoteDate']